# Difficulty calculating Law of Sines in Java

Tags: java, trigonometry

In this, I'm trying to follow law of sines in order to find angle A. The correct answer for this is 39.41 but for some reason, I'm not getting the correct inverse sine value. How can I fix this?

[Visualization of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS6nC.jpg)

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
public class test
{
    public static void calculateAzimuth()
    {
        double a = 90;
        double A = 0;
        double c = 132.3459;
        double C = 111;
        
        //         a          C     c
        //sine^-1( 90* ( (sine111) /132.3459)) = A
        C = sin(toRadians(C));
        A = C/c; 
        A = (A*a);
        A = asin(A);
        System.out.println("Angle " + A);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `toDegrees` on your result

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a = 90;
    double A = 0;
    double c = 132.3459;
    double C = 111;

    A = asin( sin(toRadians(C)) / c * a);
    System.out.println("Angle " + toDegrees(A));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not converting A to a value in degrees.  It's still in radians.

Comment: Should I do that when I initialize A?